# How to give scroll view on TextView using java for android

Tags: android, scroll, textview, scrollbar, scrollview

Hi my code can any any one tell me how to scroll `text` in `textview` for `android`.

```
physical = new TextView(this);
positionView.setTextView(getResources().getString(R.string.textviewp), 0,"Physical", physical, ImageType.TEXT_VIEW_GOAL);
physical.setId(R.id.physical);
physical.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
physical.setTextSize(18);
physical.setTypeface(fonts);
physical.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
physical.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
physical.setOnLongClickListener(OnLongClickListener);
ScrollGoalRelativeLayout.addView(physical);
```

Answer (score 3):

set the android:maxLines and `android:scrollbars = "vertical"` properties of textview in xml file in layout.

After that use the `TexView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())` in your code.